# Search in front end Indexing product Id, I want add supplier id also . How can i achieve this?

Tags: frontend, search, catalogsearch

Search in front end Indexing product Id.I want add supplier id  also for search index , I am using udropship extensions for supplier management.

Can any one suggest me how can we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I donot what is in extension.

But as per as,Magento  you have assign the ***supplier ids in a magento attribute*** then you can  search products by supplier id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  udropship extensions  adding new product attribute  udropship vendor. In udropship vendor attribute supplier Id and supplier name are custom fields.  I have to add supplier Id field  to Indexing. So that In front end search if i give supplier Id result should load.